# New line for custom emmet snippets

Tags: json, emmet

I'm adding some custom snippets for Emmet, but I can't figure out how to get things on new lines.

Here is a sample snippets.json containing a sample custom snippet.

```
{
  "html": {
    "abbreviations": {
      "img": "<img src='' alt='' title='' />"
    }
  }
}
```

Which outputs

```
<img src="" alt="" title="">
```

I would like it to output

```
<img src="" 
     alt="" 
     title=""
>
```

I have tried adding `\\n` in various places and also simply putting the code in the json file on new lines, but can't get anything working.

**Any ideas how I can do this?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems as if "\n" doesn't work under the "abbreviations" object, but it does work under the "snippets" object. So I guess that's the way to go for now. Unless someone else knows how to get it working under the "abbreviations" object.

Comment: also note the use of single and double quotes `'abb': 'first line \n second line'` does not work but `'abb': "first line \n second line"` does.

Answer (score 1):

i had before the same question!!!
now **i did it** by reading your question lol!

I use the editplus.com(on windows 10:x64) so i edit snippets.json then for carriage return i wrote like in php : \r\n

so now i insert this into there html :

```
"cc:noie": "<!--[if !IE]><!-->\n\t${child}|\n<!--<![endif]-->",  <----this comma
            "php": "<?php\r\n?>"   <-----------------------------------this code
        },

        "abbreviations": {
```

now i have php then i press tab transforming in that,directly in a blank php file!
i don't know the place where you will use it will work in the same matter

lol your abreviation works here in editplus editor

```
"img": "<img src='' \r\nalt='' \r\ntitle='' />"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, under `abbreviations` section code is parsed, constructed into a tree and formatted according to applied filters and output profiles. Thus, your option is either use `snippet` with newlines or create a custom filter that will format you code as expected.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such option like newline in Emmets at all. By visiting the following link you can check the Emmets cheatsheet:

https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/